# Regex to match a specific expression format

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that will match a specific expression in the following format:

```
name = value
```

However, I need it to not match:

```
name.extra = value
```

I have the following regex:

```
([\w\@\-]+) *(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=) *([^\s\']+)
```

which matches the first expression, but also matches the second expression (`extra = value`).

I need a regex that will match only the first expression and not the second (i.e. with a dot).

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind assertion.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to grab something from code. Technically, it wouldn't be invalid to be able to write something like `name    .   extra` (spaces in between), but this is so rare that I haven't seen such bad code myself. If you can assume there would be no such case, then it can be solved easily with negative look-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookbehind assertion (`?<!`) might be what you are looking for.

For a simple assignment: `(?<!\.)\b(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)`

**summary:**

- `(?<!\.)` = prevent the character `.` at that location
- `\b` = beginning of a word

The captured words are:

- \1 = destination name
- \2 = source name

and using the regex you specified, this should give something near this:

`(?<!\.)\b([\w\@\-]+) *(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=) *([^\s\']+)`

Comment: You should at least try to mirror whatever the OP has worked out.

Comment: But the above regex will fail for "name <= value" or "name >= value"

Comment: fixed. I forgot the spaces in the last regex, still the idea is the same as in the first assignment regex.

Comment: @DoesntMatter Thanks. I was trying this in RegexBuddy but I noticed some issues. When I use this: `(?<!.)([\w\@\-]+) *(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=) *([^\s\']+)` it works but it doesn't match when I have a space before the expression e.g. `  name = value` will not match. Can you fix this?!

Comment: Ok, I changed it to this: `(?<!\.)\b([\w\@\-]+) *(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=) *([^\s\']+)` and it works ok now. Cheers.

Comment: Also, kindly edit the answer to reflect so I can select this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `^` beginning and `$` ending to your expression

```
^([\w\@\-]+) *(\=|\>|\>\=|\<|\<\=) *([^\s\']+)$
```

Comment: I dont know why this answer got negative votes. But technically it is correct. Check [This](http://www.regex101.com/r/pG2hW1)

Comment: @om39a Because it's presumptuous to assume OP only wanted to match a single line, nor whitespace on either end, or disregard more complex expressions `x = (name = y);`.

Comment: @mario I agree with you.. But I am Curious to know how it can be handled. By using negative look behind and starting of the word? Like this `(?<!.)\b`

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you're using, but it sounds like you don't need to use regexes at all.

If you're using PHP, then use the `explode` function to break apart on the `=`.  Then check to see if the argument name has a period in it.

Comment: I have PHP and Regex Tags on the question. Also, trust me when I say I know what I need, and I need Regex.